# SQL Complains that Management Tools are not installed, but they are

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, installation

When I try to create a new Maintenance Plan in SQL Server, I get the following warning:

> The action you attempted to perform on
>   a remote instance of SQL Server has
>   failed because the action requires a
>   SQL Server component that is not
>   installed on the remote computer. To
>   proceed, install SQL Server 2005
>   Management Tools on the remote
>   computer, and then try again. For more
>   information, see "How to: Install SQL
>   Server 2005 (Setup)" in SQL Server
>   2005 Books Online, or find the article
>   on MSDN at 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=57083
>   . (ObjectExplorer)

However, the tools are installed, AFAIK.  I'm connecting to the local machine.  Here's a screenshot of both the error message alongside SQL Server telling me it won't install the management tools because they are already there.

[image]

(previous step [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/lianza/3201848963/))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - nevermind on this.  The response is simply a bit misleading.  It's only complaining about **part** of what I was asking to install.  When I decided to progress, it did in fact install some things.